# App shown on Android Emulator but crashes on Real Device and viceversa

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio. Android version is 3.2.1. 
I have been working on an application which uses API 21 and just completed my Database.Then I run the application on my real device (Danny Genius Tablet)  which is Lollipop (5.1) it simply just make an app with the name of my application's package name and does not open at all by showing message "App Name "stopped working.
After trying many solutions nothing happened.
When I run it on my Tablet Logcat showed me that

```
06-20 19:06:30.162 716-737/? E/SensorService: activeConnections...
06-20 19:06:30.182 716-737/? E/SensorService: activeConnections...
06-20 19:06:30.182 716-737/? E/SensorService: activeConnections...
06-20 19:06:30.198 26859-26859/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder, PID: 26859
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder/com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder.WelcomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder.WelcomeScreen.onCreate(WelcomeScreen.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder.WelcomeScreen.onCreate(WelcomeScreen.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder:drawable/black" (7f060055)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060055 a=-1 r=0x7f060055}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2690)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3791)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:524)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:215)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:211)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:206)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.user.offlinemobilefinder.WelcomeScreen.onCreate(WelcomeScreen.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: post stack-trace

Comment: You could have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to get properly started on the problem solving and maybe then update the question with any relevant details.

Comment: can u pls post your crash stack

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to right direction.As I am new to Android Studio So I didn't know where the actual error was I have uploaded what was shown in logcat.